# dict1[d] = c adds only last item in list2 as a value in dictionary, how can I solve it?

Tags: python

```
dict1 = {}
list1 = []
list2 = []

x = input("Enter something: ").split(',')

if len(x) % 2 == 1:
    b = input("please, add one more thing: ")
    x.append(b)

for A in x[:len(x)//2]:
    list1.append(A)
for B in x[(len(x)//2):]:
    list2.append(B)
for d in list1:
    for c in list2:
        dict1[d] = c

print(dict1)
```

when I enter "a,b,c,d"
The output is {'a': 'd', 'b': 'd'}, I want {'a': 'c', 'b': 'd'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your loop logic:

```
for d in list1:
    for c in list2:
        dict1[d] = c
```

The inner loop repeatedly overwrites dict1[d]; only the last element is obtained.  I think that what you want is ordered pairs from the two lists.

```
for d, c in zip(list1, list2):
    dict1[d] = c
```

It would help to know what you're trying to accomplish; this seems to be a very uncomfortable way to build a directory.

Without `zip`, do your own correspondence:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    dict1[list1[i]] = list2[i]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't learnt zip yet. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Oh, that's better ^_^ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

zip() function can be used in this case

```
dict1 = {}
list1 = []
list2 = []

x = input("Enter something: ").split(',')

if len(x) % 2 == 1:
    b = input("please, add one more thing: ")
    x.append(b)

for A in x[:len(x)//2]:
    list1.append(A)
for B in x[(len(x)//2):]:
    list2.append(B)

for ele in zip(list1, list2):
    dict1[ele[0]] = ele[1]
print dict1
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the initialization here just use `dict` and `zip` but slice the list in half.

```
x = input("Enter something: ").split(',')

if len(x) % 2 == 1:
    b = input("please, add one more thing: ")
    x.append(b)

h = len(x)//2
dict1 = dict(zip(x[:h], x[h:]))
```

Comment: I haven't learnt Zip yet, my lecturer won't accept that. One guy already answered my question. Thanks! <3